# PHP row deletion

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm doing a guestbook for a school project. What I have been able to do is to delete posts in it. Unfortunately when double clicking the submit button for delete it deletes all posts.

What I need it to do is to delete a single post (the post you want deleted or the entire postrow) when you press the corresponding button to the POST). I'm a bit stuck so any help would be very nice!

Here's my code for the guestbook page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Välkommen till gästboken!</h1>
    <h2>Posta till Gästboken</h2>
    <form action="home.php" method="post">  
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Titel:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="titel" style="width: 600px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inlägg:</td>
              <td><textarea name="inlägg" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="postknapp" value="Posta" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<p>
    <a href="logga_ut.php">Logga ut</a>
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if($_SESSION['login'] == 1) {    //om sessionen är 1 så

    // Connect to the database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("guestbookdatabase");

//******************************************************************//
//Display stuff
echo "<h1>Nuvarande Poster</h1>";

if ($_POST['postknapp']) {
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['titel']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['inlägg']);
    $UserID = $_POST['UserID'];

    if ($title && $message) {
         //Lägg till i databasen
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook (Title,Post,Username,UserID) VALUES  ('$title','$message','$username', $UserID)");
         echo "Ditt inlägg har lagts till i gästboken!";
    } else
        echo "Du har inte fyllt i nödvändig information för att kunna göra ett inlägg.";
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY PostID DESC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
         $id = $row['PostID'];
         $name = $row['Username'];
         $title = $row['Title'];
         $message = $row['Post'];
         $date = $row['Timestamp'];

         $message = nl2br($message);

         echo "<div> 
         Av <b>$name</b> vid <b>$date</b><br /> 
         <h2>$title</h2> <p>
         $message  <p>
         <div align = 'right'>
         </div></div><hr />"; 
         ?>
         <form action="home.php" method="get">
         <input type='submit' name='Raderaknapp' value='Ta bort inlägget' />
         </form>
         <?php

        if ($_GET['Raderaknapp']) {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE PostID ='".$id."' AND  Username='".$UserID."'");
            echo "Inlägget har tagits bort!";
        }
    }
} else
    echo "Inga inlägg hittades.";

//*****************************************************************//

mysql_close();
?>

<?php

} else { // om session inte är 1 så 
    echo "Du har INTE tillåtelse till gästboken! Klicka på länken för att logga in!";
?>
    <p>
    <br/><a href="index.html">Till login >></a>
<?php   
}

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are mistakenly doing your `DELETE` inside your `while` loop - so for every ID it outputs, you delete it! You probably want to get an ID from the POST operation outside of this loop, and if it is non-zero, run the `DELETE`.

Comment: Try modifying your button thus:  `<input type='submit' name='Raderaknapp_<?php echo $id ?>' value='Ta bort inlägget' />`. You can then detect this name outside of the loop.

Comment: No, it won't fix everything - I left the detection of the suggested button to you. In general it is best to take answers here as _hints_ to go forward - it isn't good practice to expect people to write your code for you, nor for someone here to provide one. (Some helpers here are too helpful, which can be counterproductive to learning!).

Comment: Here's a good approach to debugging the problem. At the start of your PHP code (say after your `session_start()`) put this in temporarily: `if ($_POST) { echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>'; exit(); }`. That will show you what has been submitted, and you can use that info to help you detect which row the user wishes to delete.

Comment: No i want to do it on my own but i don't recognise what i have missed in my code?

Comment: Have you updated the submit button as I suggested?

Comment: Could it work if i put: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id['PostID']?>" /> in the post form?

Comment: No, I think `$id` is an integer variable, so it won't contain things like an array would. Perhaps you meant `$row['PostID']`, which has the same value as `$id` (it's just the latter is quicker to write).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24717/discussion-between-halfer-and-william-bergendahl)

Answer (score 1):

Your code literally says "if `$_GET['Raderknapp']` is set and nonzero (in other words, is truthy), delete the row". There is no condition on `$_GET['Raderaknapp']`, nor any way to identify which row you are trying to delete.

Comment: Can you show me a way in my code how i can create this identifier and be able to delete the row?